# Android java SQLite queries and single quotes

Tags: android

When attempting to query text fields in SQLite I get force closes if the text field contains a single quote character. I know why it's happening but how can I fix it?

Comment: Your query causes the exception? Can you list it in your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `?` operator. Your query will be like `FIELD=?`, and the next argument to the `query()` call will be a String array where you provide an argument for each `?` you used.

Comment: Can you provide an example? I tried searching online but can't seem to across anything. E.g one example that produces an error if it contains a single quote in the field (s) is "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Todo WHERE Subject=" + "' + s + '", null);

Comment: It's really straightforward. `query(myUri, null, "FIELD=?", new String[] { "That's how you do it" }, null);`

Comment: Ok I figured out how to do it in raw queries but what about Android sqlite queries?

Comment: All query() commands in the Android API have "selection" and "selectionArgs" parameters.