# Do you need a different query when using a string as a parameter to search

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I am querying my db.  When I use an int for the selection part I get the info returned I want.  When I use a string for selection I get nothing returned. Is there a different way to query when using a string or am I doing something wrong.  This function worked when I passed in an int, but when I pass in a string it does not work.  I used breakpoints and the parameters are correct going into the function, but it does not retrieve the data from the db.

Here is the code

```
 public String childFound(String item_name)throws Exception
{

    Cursor c = db.query(DB_TABLE, new String[] { KEY_INSPECTION_ID, KEY_ITEM_NAME},
            "item_name="+ item_name, null, null, null, null);

       int id=c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ITEM_NAME);
        c.moveToFirst();
        String result=c.getString(id);
       c.close();
       return result;

}
```

If I change the String item_name to int inspectionItem it works.  I am also including where I declared my variable for the db.

```
 public class InspectionRecordsTableDBAdapter {
private static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
private static final String KEY_INSPECTION_ID = "inspection_id";
private static final String KEY_PARENT_NAME = "parent_name";
private static final String KEY_ITEM_NAME = "item_name";
private static final String KEY_COMMENT = "comment";
private static final String KEY_STATUS = "status";
private static final String DB_TABLE = "inspection_records";
private Context context;
private SignalSetDBHelper dbHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase db;
private SQLiteOpenHelper openHelper;
```

If you need more code let me know.

Comment: U should use "?'"  Google for query selectionArgs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"item_name="+ item_name
```

should be

```
"item_name='"+ item_name + "'"
```

Think you are missing the quotes

Comment: Bad idea. What if item_name contains single quote?

Comment: @Selvin, I am a newbie, how would you fix that?

Comment: Even better try: Cursor c = db.query(DB_TABLE, new String[] { KEY_INSPECTION_ID, KEY_ITEM_NAME},
            "item_name=?", item_name, null, null, null);

Comment: Try [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4435228/android-java-sqlite-queries-and-single-quotes)